# Why is this stubbed method that should return nil returning something else?

Tags: testing, rspec

I am stubbing a method like this:

```
User.stub_chain(:something).and_return(nil)
```

When I'm testing, I want this code to raise an error:

```
raise NameError if User.something.blank?
```

The problem is that `User.something.blank?` is not `true`, even though it should be stubbed with a `nil` value. `User.something` is actually

```
#[RSpec::Mocks::Mock:0x795359c @name=nil]
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your stub code or the code you're trying to test, as evidenced by the following passing test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

class User ; end
describe "" do
  it "" do
    User.stub_chain(:something).and_return(nil)
    expect { raise NameError if User.something.blank? }.to raise_error(NameError)
  end
end
```

You must have some problem elsewhere in your code.